# Translating html and javascript form info into rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble getting this to work in my rails form. I wanted to change the file upload button, and I managed to find this code which makes the button look right and also displays the name of the selected file.

*EDIT - I did not include the rest of this form because it is gigantic, but this appears within a form_for block.

```
<div class="form-group">

  <label class="btn btn-danger" for="my-file-selector">
      <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none" 
      onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html(this.files[0].name)">
      Avatar Upload
  </label>
  <span class='label text-secondary' id="upload-file-info"></span>

</div>
```

The issue I'm having is linking it to the image field in my database. As it is now it doesn't save the image. I need to translate this so that it will work like I had it before. This is my form upload button that works with rails, but it doesn't show the name of the file selected.

```
<div class="form-group">

  <label class="btn btn-danger">
    Avatar Upload
    <span style="display:none;">
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </span>
  </label>

</div>
```

How can I combine the two to get the desired effect? See images here. The first button is mine, it uploads images just fine, only it doesn't display the name of the file. The second button is what it looks like with style="display:none" turned off. It shows the filename. (The second button uses the code from sfate's answer below.) I need it to look like the first button.

The third button is what I'm trying to achieve, only I cannot figure out how to make it work with rails file_field and my :image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Seem like you're using `file_field` in a wrong way.
`file_field` can be used only in a `form_for` block.
More info: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html</s>

To archive what you want - you can use `file_field_tag` like this:

```erb
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="btn btn-danger">
    Avatar Upload
    <span>
      <%= file_field_tag 'image', accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg' %>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:**

According to edited question.
You can't get file name dynamically on file select, javascript is still required:

```erb
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="btn btn-danger" for="my-file-selector">
      <%= f.file_field :image, id: 'my-file-selector', style: 'display: none', onchange: "document.getElementById('upload-file-info').textContent = this.value" %>
      Avatar Upload
    </label>
    <span class='label text-secondary' id="upload-file-info"></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

For a case when you just need to render a filename from existing object (`@user` for this example):

```erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="btn btn-danger" for="my-file-selector">
      <%= f.file_field :image, id: 'my-file-selector', style: 'display: none' %>
      Avatar Upload
    </label>
    <span class='label text-secondary' id="upload-file-info">
      <%= @user.image.original_filename %>
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also note that `original_filename` method exists on attachments with `paperlip`or `carrierwave` gems, you might not have it on `image` object if you're not using them.

Comment: I didn't put the code for the whole form in because I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: You saved my life. :)